# How to cause a postback using jquery autocomplete on option select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, postback

## TEST AREA

I have created a simple jquery-ui autocomplete demo.

**QUESTION**

How can I cause a postback to occur when an option is selected from the list?

**HTML**

```
<select id="ddl"></select>
<input id="field" type="text"></input>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#field").autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        __doPostBack("#ddl", ""); //Postback will not occur here?
    }
});
```

**NOTES**

The rest of the code in this demo is not required, it is simply there to show that an option is being successfully selected.

I can't see what is preventing the postback from occuring. I simply want a postback to occur when the user picks any option from the list generated by the autocomplete.

Comment: There's a problem before the postback statement; http://jsfiddle.net/g23vrfoe/2/ the alert statement never pops up.

Comment: It works as described for me. What browser are you using? Can you please specify the steps you take.

Comment: The alert works fine for me. Appears on option select as expected.

Comment: Ok, may be I'm not using it as intended then.

Comment: Press "A", select an option, see message.

Comment: @Obsidian, not sure you use a prepended `#` in calls to __doPostBack. This is a JQuery convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding values to the autocomplete widget fixed it for me.

*Note that the "select" function only fires when I click on one of the autocomplete options.  It does not fire if I only type in the name of one of the options.*

Check out the updated code below:

```
<select id="ddl" />
<input id="field" type="text" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var availableAutocompleteValues = [
   "jquery",
   "java",
   "javascript"
];
$("#field").autocomplete({
    source: availableAutocompleteValues
});
$("#field").autocomplete({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        __doPostBack("#ddl", ""); //Postback will not occur here?
    }
});
</script>
```